# using LibVLC in C++ Project [Mac OS X - Xcode]

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, libvlc

I am writing an application that catch a stream video from a wifi camera and I am using LibVLC to retrieve the video.

So, before implementing my application, I have tested LibVLC with the example code, but it crashes on function **libvlc_media_new_location**

I am using this Framework on Mac OS X El Capitan with Xcode, the dialect of C++ is std=c++11 and libc++ (LLVM).

This is the example code that doesn't work:

```
libvlc_instance_t * inst;
libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
libvlc_media_t *m;

/* Load the VLC engine */
inst = libvlc_new (0, NULL);

/* Create a nxxew item, this is the line that crashes*/
m = libvlc_media_new_location (inst, "http://mycool.movie.com/test.mov"); 

/* Create a media player playing environement */
mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (m);

/* No need to keep the media now */
libvlc_media_release (m);
```

Could you help me please ? 
Thanks in advance for response.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be the bug in `libvlc` 2.2.x which not allow use it outside `VLC.app` (due to fail load plugins, since plugins try search `libvlccore.dylib` in wrong place). As workaround you should use slightly modified VLC tree. You could get it already prepared from [one of my projects](https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera.js/releases/download/v0.2.5/WebChimera.js_v0.2.5_electron_v0.33.9_VLC_v2.2.3_x64_osx.tar.gz).

Comment: First thanks to answer me. In second where do i put them ?

Comment: place `lib` folder from archive above, near your executable file.

Comment: Ok it is compiled and now it does not crashing but in console it print a series of error like core access and so on.. So the video do not start !

Comment: Please check if `lib\vlc\lib` contains `libvlccore.8.dylib` symlink to `../../libvlccore.8.dylib`. At some conditions when you copy symlinks  on OS X - it could copy file symlink pointed to instead of symlink as-is.

Comment: This is my procedure, unzip archive by terminal, to preserve integrity of link, so from fast check i have seen that all link are correct... Any idea ?!

Comment: Could you copy libvlc log somewhere?

Comment: Do you refer terminal output ? If not, where can i find it ?

Comment: RSATom, sorry to jump the thread - are we aware of the issue? Did we fix it for 3.0?

Comment: @feepk, don't know. I didn't report it. And I didn't try 3.0.

Comment: @feepk, if I remember correctly, the issue was introduced with VLC 2.2.0, VLC 2.1.5 didn't have that issue.